# Is there a FireFox cookie manager that's suitable for Tor Browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, cookies

In Chrome, [Vanilla Cookie Manager](https://github.com/laktak/vanilla-chrome) saves whitelisted cookies outside Chrome's usual cookie space, so that Chrome can be told to erase all cookies and site data.

Is there a similar add-on for FireFox that'd provide a cookie whitelist for Tor Browser?  All the ones I've tried appear to work by deleting the cookies themselves, so they cannot save cookies in Tor Browser.

Answer (score -1):

there is a very same addon for firefox called [cookie quick manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookie-quick-manager/) when you installed it, you could protect cockies of intended websites and kill the others.

But there is still a question, why not using `tor` instead of `tor-browser`?
By using **tor** which you can install in your distro and route your network traffic through `tor` network, besides you can use Bridges.

Also, you could even use your firefox without any thinking about using tor-browser, and that's possible via traffic director addon in firefox called [**Switchy Omega**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/switchyomega/).
So when you want you can handle your packets to be routed without **tor** (**directly**) or packets routed through tor profile you can move over a box in the addon.

Even better you can add conditions like if you want website x to go through tor and but not y, you will have only to add a condition to the tor profile in the add, believe it or not, it's super simple.

Comment: Never use Firefox over Tor. Tor Browser exists because regular browser will compromise your anonymity when running over Tor. See Tor Browser Design Document, https://2019.www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/

Answer (score -1):

Don't use the Tor browser; use Tor and proxy Firefox through it.
There's nothing special with Tor, it has just a different TLD.
The regular cookie management extensions should work except you're using an old version of the browser which doesn't support the newer WebExtensions API.
Hope you find [Cookie Autodelete](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/cookie-autodelete/) useful.

Comment: This is false.  Tor Browser has extensive modifications that improve anonymity over Firefox.  Mozilla has reincorporated some, but many harm functionality, like by reducing javascript functionality, preventing window resizing, etc.  It's natural to ask how to regain functionality lost by using Tor browser, like ad blocking or saving and restoring cookies, without sacrificing Tor browser's extra protections.

Comment: Never use Firefox over Tor. Tor Browser exists because regular browser will compromise your anonymity when running over Tor. See Tor Browser Design Document, https://2019.www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/