Turn on cookies with tor
Is there a way to turn on cookies with Tor? I am only using it to stop snooping ISP, nothing else. I have seen several people ask, but they are always answered with "Its possible but don't do it" and no explanation.

Does this help: https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/8660/31769 - use both answers.

Use an isolated regular browser and it will work as you expect it. I recommend VirtualBox or KVM virtual machine routed through Tor's transparent port. It will ensure that no leak will happen and you will have just a normal browsing capabilities. Be sure to use DNS-over-HTTPS that is built-in in like all modern browsers nowdays. I recommend Firefox with it's cookie separation feature already implemented

That does not answer my question. Can you turn on cookies with the Tor Browser?

no, not with Tor browser - it's tailored on the source code level to prevent privacy leaks at all costs because it's launched as an application, not a VM. So - many functions are tweaked or sacrificed for the sake of keeping the safety at it's best in the case. The answer for your question is in my answer - you will achieve exactly what and how you want safely if you will do as I said

is that portable? (ex. can have all data on a USB drive or sd card)

yes you certainly can! just put a VM's drive image file on the USB drive or sd card
